# Breeze not returning List<int> Plain Object

Tags: c#, breeze

Hi i am using `Breeze` with c#

I have one **EventDto** and added it in `DbContext` as well, however it is not exist in Database.

My EventDto is as Below:

```
public partial class EventDto
{
    [Key]
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventTitle { get; set; }
    public string EventDescription { get; set; }
    public List<int> Ids { get; set; }
}
```

When i call using breeze service it does not return "Ids".

Any one can solve this?

Thanks in advance.